# Add percentage label on Google treemap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a dynamic Google Treemap Chart, it works well but I want to add the percentage label on all sections (rectangles)

Is there an option to set it to autocalculate? Or a way to modify the title label to calculate it and add it?

Comment: @WhiteHat I hope automatically, deppending on box size.

Comment: sorry, there's no auto-calculate feature, can you describe how to calculate the percentage? we can use a data view to perform the calculation...